# unittest celery task assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing, celery, assert

I have some celery task. I want to test it via unittest.

I'm doing something very similar to:

```
class TestMe(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_celery_task(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, celery_task.apply, args)
```

what is strange for me:

this assert fails, because `ValueError not raised`, but during executing process I can see ValueError as a result of this celery task.

I'm not sure, but it looks like assert is checking faster than ValueError is rising. 
Is it possible to check the result of executed celery task?
or how it may be tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't possibly work. When you enqueue a Celery task, all that happens is that you put a message into the queue for a separate process to pick up; it is that process that runs the task and, potentially, raises the exception.

If you want to check that the task itself raises ValueError, then you should call the task, not the delay function:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, celery_task, args)
```

Comment: will this celery task runs locally or it will be added into my queue?

Comment: coo, if locally. It looks like it works for me. I've got a new error, if it's not because of unexpected executing of celery task, I'll accept your approach

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 options here.

1) Try to call `get()` on apply(). Here is what you will get:

```
class TestMe(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_celery_task(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, celery_task.apply().get(), args)
```

2) You can either enable eager mode by setting 'task_always_eager' to `True`, however it does not guarantee that your code will be able to catch up.

3) A better option would be to mock the celery tasks. From the point of unit testing it is not actually correct to test a unit of code with actual 'alive' part of systems like celery.
Here is a sample of code taken from celery [testing documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html).

```
from pytest import raises

from celery.exceptions import Retry

# for python 2: use mock.patch from `pip install mock`.
from unittest.mock import patch

from proj.models import Product
from proj.tasks import send_order

class test_send_order:

    @patch('proj.tasks.Product.order')  # < patching Product in module above
    def test_success(self, product_order):
        product = Product.objects.create(
            name='Foo',
        )
        send_order(product.pk, 3, Decimal(30.3))
        product_order.assert_called_with(3, Decimal(30.3))

    @patch('proj.tasks.Product.order')
    @patch('proj.tasks.send_order.retry')
    def test_failure(send_order_retry, product_order):
        product = Product.objects.create(
            name='Foo',
        )

        # set a side effect on the patched method
        # so that it raises the error we want.
        product_order.side_effect = OperationalError()

        with raises(Retry):
            send_order(product.pk, 3, Decimal(30.6))
```

Comment: this is a part of integration testing, that's why I'm trying to test my system, but not mocks :)

Comment: Try the first option. `.get()` should work in your case